# Avoid three for-loops

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way l can optimize the code below without using 3 for-loops

```
for obj in firstArray:
    newListKeys.append(obj.key)

for key in anotherArray:
    if key not in newListKeys:
        soonToDelete.append(key)

for key in soonToDelete:
    del anotherArray[key]
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Removing all keys in one array that don't appear in the other?

Comment: @ErnestAppiah, yep, you're right, sorry about that.

Comment: you can replace your first two lines with obj.keys()

Comment: You're using key as an index in the last step. I guess that's not what you mean.

Comment: Wait, what type is `anotherArray`?  If it's a list, `del anotherArray[key]` will work by position, and so probably not do what's expected.  If it's a dictionary, then it has a terrible name.

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehensions

```
# This replaces the first for loop
newListKeys = [obj.key for obj in firstArray]
# This replaces the second and third loops
anotherArray = [item for item in anotherArray if item in newListKeys]
```

Comment: It would be probably smarter to replace a list with a set. `newListKeys = set(obj.key for obj in firstArray)`. Cheaper lookups.

Comment: Possibly, but it depends on how large the initial array of objects is.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner using list comprehension:

```
anotherArray = [a for a in anotherArray if a in {obj.key for obj in firstArray}]
```

It's easier to create a new list than to remove elements from a existing list.

Comment: Lists don't have a `.keys()` method

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
anotherSet = set.intersection(set(obj.key for obj in firstArray), set(anotherArray))
```

Returns the set of unique keys that are common between `newListKeys` and `anotherArray`. If a list is required, can be cast to a list: `anotherArray = list(set.intersection(newListKeys, set(anotherArray)))`. Note that it will only return one copy of each key in `anotherArray`, but then again, if it is a list of keys, it's cannot be duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Another one liner option:

```
anotherArray = [e for e in firstArray for key in anotherArray if e.key == key]
```